# Harmonizing Env Variables between packages

Tags: react-native, redux, environment-variables, vite

We currently have a monorepo configuration consisting of our Mobile & Web Applications, and a shared Redux Store.

The Web application utilizes Vite, and the `import.meta.env.ENV` syntax. The Mobile package uses `react-native-dotenv` for env resolution.

The problem is that both client packages use the same Redux Store package. However, the Redux store needs to access env variables from both clients.

This means that `import.meta.env` will not work for the mobile application, and using the DotEnv values will not work for the Web Application.

What would be a suitable way to harmonize these?